# SQL - data from select in excel file

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql

i have next query

```
select no,
item
from myTable
```

and I get next table

```
no      item
 1        a
 2        b
 3        c
 4        d
```

I use tsql, Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.
Is there any way to write here some code to export table from my select in excel...

Comment: you want to query the data which is present in your excel sheet?

Comment: no, i need from sql select in excel

Comment: so you need to write query in excel sheet to fetch the data from Sql ?

Comment: @K.K  I would assume from the question that they want to export the data returned into an excel spreadsheet.

Comment: can i write query in my microsoft studio to export data to excel?

Comment: What is the purpose of your export to excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to write a query in SSMS and then export the results to excel, but you can connect an excel sheet to SQL Server and run queries into an data table from there using the `From Other Sources - From SQL Server` menu in the `Data` tab on the ribbon:

[image]

This is good if you want to build on that data within Excel and you need to refresh the data but don't want to update your formulas.  There are obviously security implications with this as users of the Worksheet may be able to access other data on your server.

If you want to simply export an Excel file with data in to a file store, you would need to use SSRS and a report subscription.  Alternatively, if you simply want to save the results of your query to a file, you can either copy and paste manually or choose to `Save Your Results To Text` in SSMS:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

from your excel sheet you can create a dynamic connection between a SQL Server database and your Excel workbook. 
Follow the steps in below link.
[Steps to Connect a SQL Server database to your workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-a-SQL-Server-database-to-your-workbook-22c39d8d-5b60-4d7e-9d4b-ce6680d43bad)

Comment: Per the SO guidelines: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.**"